# Way to access resource files in python

Tags: python

What is the proper way to access resources in python programs.

Basically in many of my python modules I end up writing code like that:

```
  DIRNAME = os.path.split(__file__)[0]

  (...) 

  template_file = os.path.join(DIRNAME, "template.foo")
```

Which is OK but:

- It will break if I will start to use python zip packages
- It is boilerplate code

In Java I had a function that did exactly the same --- but worked both when code was lying in bunch of folders and when it was packaged in `.jar` file.

Is there such function in Python, or is there any other pattern that I might use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll want to look at using either [get_data](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) in the stdlib or [pkg_resources](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) from setuptools/distribute.  Which one you use probably depends on whether you're already using distribute to package your code as an egg.

Comment: OK this is a pythonic answer. get_data looks interesting, but pkg_resources is way to intimidating, but I'll definietely look into it when I'll start using distutils to package my project.

Comment: I'm looking for similar solution. `get_data` is great but I need to get the file-like object for this file, not the contents of the file directly. Is there an elegant way?

Comment: @zegkljan The most pythonic way is to wrap it with BytesIO (StringIO in Py2): `file_like = BytesIO(get_data(__package__, 'filename.dat'))`

Comment: Nowadays, the proper way to access resources is to use the `importlib.resources` module. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497763/1513933) below.

Answer (score 14):

Since version 3.7 of Python, the proper way to access a file in resources is to use the [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources) library.

One can, for example, use the `path` function to access a particular file in a Python package:

```py
import importlib.resources

with importlib.resources.path("your.package.templates", "template.foo") as template_file:
    ...
```

Starting with Python 3.9, this package introduced the `files()` API, to be preferred over the legacy API.

One can, use the `files` function to access a particular file in a Python package:

```py
template_res = importlib.resources.files("your.package.templates").joinpath("template.foo")
with importlib.resources.as_file(template_res) as template_file:
    ...
```

For older versions, I recommend to install and use the [importlib-resources](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. The documentation also explains in detail how to migrate your old implementation using `pkg_resources` to `importlib-resources`.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to understand how we could combine the two aspect togather

1. Loading for resources in native filesystem
2. Packaged in zipped files

Reading through the quick tutorial on zipimport : http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/zipimport/

I see the following example:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'zipimport_example.zip')
import os
import zipimport
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('zipimport_example.zip')
module = importer.load_module('example_package')
print module.__file__
print module.__loader__.get_data('example_package/README.txt')
```

I think that output of __file__ is "zipimport_example.zip/example_package/__init__.pyc"

Need to check how it looks from inside.

But then we could always do something like this:

```
if ".zip" in example_package.__file__:
    ... 
    load using get_data
else:
    load by building the correct file path
```

**[Edit:] I have tried to work out the example a bit better.**

If the the package gets imported as zipped file then, two things happen

1. __file__ contains ".zip" in it's path.
2. __loader__ is available in the name space

If these two conditions are met then within the package you could do:

```
print __loader__.get_data(os.path.join('package_name','README.txt'))
```

else the module was loaded normally and you can follow the regular approach to loading the file.

Comment: you should use `os.path.join('example_package', 'README.txt')` if you want to be platform independent

Comment: @jb: Does this solution looks better to you.

Comment: Definetely interesting answer --- i'll most probably stick to distutils if just pushing python code would be to cumbersome at some point. But I think that this could be used in GAE code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html) standard python module could be an answer...

EDIT: well, not the use of the module directly, but using `sys.path` as shown in the example could be a good way:

- I have a zip file `test.zip` with one python module `test` and a file `test.foo` inside
- to test that for the zipped python module `test` can be aware of of `test.foo`, it contains this code:

c

```
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'test.foo')):
    print 'OK'
else:
    print 'KO'
```

Test looks ok:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, r'D:\DATA\FP12210\My Documents\Outils\SVN\05_impl\2_tools\test.zip')
>>> import test
OK
>>>
```

So a solution could be to loop in your zip file to retrieve all python modules, and add them in `sys.path`; this piece of code would be ideally the 1st one loaded by your application.

Comment: I disagree --- zipimport can't import anything other that `.py[co]?` files. So as I stated in the question --- this code will fail if someone tried to run it from an archive.

Comment: Indeed, but the `sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/example.zip')` gives a good idea of how to do...