# Unicode Decode error using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am trying to read .res files and this is the error I get :

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 27: invalid continuation byte.`

I tried studying similar problem solutions but nothing is working out. Please find below my piece of code:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame()

    for filename in os.listdir():

        #with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        #F=filename.read().split()

        if filename.endswith(".res"):

            Data=open(filename)
            F=Data.read()
```

Comment: Is the format of your file UTF-8?  If it isn't then that's your problem.  Python is trying to read that file as UTF-8 and is failing because it's some other format.  I'd suggest that you try changing your open line to `Data=open(filename, 'rb')`

Comment: I tried doing that but end up getting b written in front of data in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

A .res file is usually a resource file written in C++ that contains compiled code which is used on Windows systems. It is not a text file, which is what your code assumes with `Data=open(filename)` and `F=Data.read()`. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935127/way-to-access-resource-files-in-python) answer on how to access resource files in Python.